# How to dynamically load class in swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swift2, dynamic-loading

If I have app A with class called Hello and in it  function called

helloworld which print "hello world" statement and I want to use this class

in another app B and dynamically load hello class in runtime and use

helloworld method can any one help me pleaseee??!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you can use `NSClassFromString`. Do keep in mind that iOS doesn't use any real namespacing so your class string will have to be `"SourceAppName.ClassName"` like so:

```
let className = "SourceAppName.SomeViewControllerOrClass"
let grabbedClass = NSClassFromString(className!) as! UIViewController.Type
let helloWorldClass = grabbedClass.init()
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Cole for your answer, but it returns nil can you explain more with sample example please
 Thanks again :)